# получение файлов из sharepoint

Tags: javascript, python, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Мне нужно подключиться к корпоративному SharePoint, чтобы проверить все папки определенного каталога на наличие файлов, и если таковые имеются, мне нужно их загрузить. Я пробовал подключаться через библиотеки office 365.sharepoint. Если у кого-то есть опыт, помогите решить эту проблему на Python

```
class SharePointHandler():

    def __init__(self, username: str, company_site: str, password: str) -> None:

        self.username = username
        self.company_site = company_site
        self.client_context = self.create_client_context(user_password=password)

    def create_client_context(self, user_password) -> None:

        try:
            ctx_authorization = AuthenticationContext(self.company_site)
            ctx_authorization.acquire_token_for_user(self.username, user_password)  # Deprecated --> must update
            client_context = ClientContext(self.company_site, ctx_authorization)

            return client_context

        except Exception as e:

            sys.exit(1)

    def map_folder(self, to_map: str) -> tuple[list[str], list[str]]:

        file_list, folder_list = [], []

        def enum_folder(parent_folder):

            parent_folder.expand(["Files", "Folders", "ModifiedBy"]).get().execute_query()

            for file in parent_folder.files:
                file_list.append(file.serverRelativeUrl)

            for folder in parent_folder.folders:
                folder_list.append(folder.serverRelativeUrl)
                enum_folder(folder)

        root_folder = self.client_context.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(to_map)

        enum_folder(root_folder)

        return file_list, folder_list
```

Comment: ну вот вы пробовали - а код ваш где. если вам нужно с чем-то помочь. код приведите. если вам нужно написать программу, то это на другой сайт.

Comment: добавил, извините первый раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле все просто оказалось.
class SharePoint:
url = "https://Ваш сайт/sites/rpa/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('Заявки')"
username = 'login'
password = 'password'
auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)

```
def sp_api(self, list_url):
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'}
    responce=requests.get(list_url,verify=False,auth=self.auth,headers=headers).json()
    return responce

def sp_api_copy(self, list_url):
    username = 'kalabin_as'
    password = 'V1qaz2wsx!'
    auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username, password)
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'}
    responce=requests.get(list_url,verify=False,auth=auth,headers=headers, stream=True)
    return responce

def files_sp(self, url):
    x = self.sp_api(url + "/files")['d']['results']
    for data in x:
        name_file = data['Name']
        address_file = data['__metadata']['id']
        file_sp = self.sp_api_copy(address_file + "/$value")
        with open(name_file, 'wb') as location:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file_sp.raw, location)
            print('FILE OK')

def folders_sp(self, url=url):
    x = self.sp_api(url + "/folders")['d']['results']
    for i in x:
        if len(x) != 0:
            print(i['__metadata']['id'])
            # self.files_sp(i['__metadata']['id'])
            sql_add(i['__metadata']['id'])
            self.folders_sp(i['__metadata']['id'])
        else:
            return i
```

А вот с библиотеками так ничего и не вышло....